# Android AppWidget update ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-appwidget

I'm getting a problem with an Appwidget on Android. I have a listView and a Button, and the Widget's update period is set up to 30 minutes.
Now i want to update the listView when the button is clicked. I have searched for this issue on the internet, but I haven't found an answer that solves the problem.
In my Code, what do I have to write at the onReceived()-method to get the widget updated?

My code:

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

private static final String ACTION_UPDATE_CLICK = "click";

private Date date;

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = updateWidgetListView(context,
                appWidgetIds[i]);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], remoteViews);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.bMorgenWidget,
                getPendingSelfIntent(context,
                        ACTION_UPDATE_CLICK));
    }

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}


private PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
    intent.setAction(action);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if (ACTION_UPDATE_CLICK.equals(intent.getAction())) {

    }
}

private RemoteViews updateWidgetListView(Context context, int appWidgetId) {

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget_layout);

    Intent svcIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
    svcIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    svcIntent.setData(Uri.parse(svcIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
    remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetId, R.id.listViewWidget,
            svcIntent);
    remoteViews.setEmptyView(R.id.listViewWidget, R.id.empty_view);
    return remoteViews;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I was wondering how to force update the data and ui inside my widget.

The solution i found is to use a public static inner service:

```
/**
 * Update Big Widget Service
 */
public static class WidgetBigUpdateService extends Service
{
    public WidgetBigUpdateService()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Context context = getBaseContext();
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, this.getClass()));
        RemoteViews bigWidgetView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_big_layout);
        refreshBigWidgetData(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds, bigWidgetView);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The method 
`refreshBigWidgetData(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds, bigWidgetView);` 
belongs to the widget and is responsible to the UI update of my widget:

```
/**
 * Asks for Big Widget Updates
 *
 * @param context
 */
private void widgetBigForceUpdate(Context context)
{
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, this.getClass()));
    onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}
```

As you can see it call the function `onUpdate()` with context, appWidgetManager and appWidgetId. This code is 100% working and i have no doubt you can adapt it to your specific use.

Hope this helps